# SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

gracias por su amable ayuda :)

En estos momentos estoy intentando enviar un correo utilizando PHPMailer a lo cual me aparece el siguiente error:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t129sm8288876vkc.0 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [186.155.13.179]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

**Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\BiciBogota\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 269
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT**


SMTP connect() failed.
Ha ocurrido un error, el mensaje no ha sido enviado: SMTP connect() failed.
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require ('conexion.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // no debes incluir tu usuario
$mail->Password = "contrasena";         // y menos tu password!
$mail->setFrom('diana.mhurtadog@gmail.com', 'contrasena787');
$mail->addAddress($correo_recibe, 'Marcela Gomez');
$mail->Subject = '¡Alguien encontró tu bici!';
$mail->msgHTML("<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang='en'>
                <head>
                    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                    <title>Título</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    Hola! ".$nombre.", desde BiciBogotá queremos informarte que al parecer alguien ha encontrado tu bici. Éstos fueron los datos que nos proporcionó: <br>

                    Datos de la bici

                    Serial: ".$serial."<br>
                    Marca: ".$marca."<br>

                    Dónde lo encontró?

                    Localidad: ".$localidad."<br>
                    Barrio: ".$barrio."<br>
                    Direccion: ".$direccion."<br><br>


                    Mensaje adicional: ".$mensaje."<br>

                    Si este mensaje ha sido de utilidad y has recuperado tu bicicleta reportalo &nbsp <button><a href=".$link.">&nbsp¡AQUÍ!&nbsp</a></button>&nbsp (o copia y pega este link: ".$link."), de esta manera ya no aparecerá más en la sección de bicicletas perdidas de tu perfil y no tendrás problemas con lo retenes de la ciudad.

                </body>
                </html>");

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error, el mensaje no ha sido enviado: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado!";
```

Las variables las recibo por post y una consulta en base de datos
Se han publicado varios errores de este tipo sin embargo las soluciones dadas no me han funcionado.. Entre otras, le quité el ; a la línea extension=php_openssl.dll de php.ini, le cambié el puerto a 465, cambié el correo de envío el cual tiene activado el permiso de acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras...

Así que si alguno tiene otra solución estoy atenta. :D

Comment: jamas incluyas tu usuario o password en linea! seguridad basica....

Answer (score 2):

El problema ocurre que PHP introduce la verificación del certificado SSL y en el servidor de correo estas utilizando un servidor no certificado, por lo tanto, tienes que desactivar la verificación, justo antes del envió ($mail->send()).

```
$mail->smtpConnect([
   'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);
```